# I cannot center the Body Element

Tags: html, css

code

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
}

li {
  float: right;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.btn {
  background: #ebc22f;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #eee;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-color: gray;
  width: 35%;
}

body h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Advanced Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Image Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Google Search</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<body>
  <h1>Google Search</h1>
  <form action="https://google.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q" alt="Enter Your Query">
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Google Search">
  </form>
</body>
```

Hi, It is just a simple question I have. I have no idea how to center the body. I have tried doing top: 50% and left 50% and that doesn't seem to work. I have also tried at adding padding on all sides but that makes the page go wonkers. Margin does the same as well. Thank for helping!

Comment: um. body should be the root element of the page’s content. everything you want to display should be inside body.

Comment: that's not valid HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
}

li {
  float: right;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}

.btn {
  background: #ebc22f;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #eee;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}

input[type=text] {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border-color: gray;
  width: 35%;
}

body h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Advanced Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Image Search</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Google Search</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>

<body>
  <h1>Google Search</h1>
  <form action="https://google.com/search">
    <input type="text" name="q" alt="Enter Your Query">
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Google Search">
  </form>
</body>
```

Just add text-align: center; to your body.
and of course your html isn't valid, And probably everything should be centered.
you did something wrong which makes change direction's or alignments.
Look at this (it helps you):
https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html